# Is My Data MNAR (Missing not at Random)?

Tags: missing-data, dyadic-data

I have a dataset that looks at asylum rates for asylum-seekers (refugee status). The data is broken down by country of origin and the host state (where they apply for asylum. I have been reading up thoroughly on the types of missing data (e.g. MAR, MCAR, etc), but I'm terribly confused as it applies to my own data for a couple of reasons.

First, after I calculate the rates, some of the rates are missing because they neither received asylum, nor were rejected. In other words, they did not received a decision and are thus pending. Therefore, there are no rates.

Second, some of the data are missing because it is probably that no one from that country applied for asylum in the host state in year *t*.

Would these be cases of missing not at random?. Most of the missing data examples seem to revolve around surveys, and I understand it when I read it. I am just having a hard time applying it to my own scenario.

**Edited**: ***the unit of analysis is dyad-year*** (host state and origin state in year T). The independent variables look at domestic explanations from the host state. So, for example, do far-Right parties in power affect asylum-rates? Do do differences in the major religion of the host state and the state of origin (where asylum-seekers originate) affect asylum-rates? I also tried to pool as much as I could with the DV in order to have sufficient amount of observations to lag the dependent variable. I originally wanted to use a GEE model, but read that it gives an unbiased explanation if the missing data are MCAR.

Comment: Is your unit of analysis the person or the country?

Comment: Hi, it's country. Country-year.

Comment: OK, I recommend you make your question text fully consistent with that.  Your "First" paragraph sounds like it's describing data at the person level--individual experiences.  Beyond that, I suspect a really good answer to your MNAR question would require familiarity with all the variables in your analysis.  So you may have some additional explaining to do.... :-)

Comment: Editing now, to further lessen the confusion. thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

The first is a case of right-censoring. Survival analysis deals with these kinds of problems.

The second is a kind of selection bias, that you might or might not want to control for. Perhaps there are ways to control for it via instrumental variables such as distance between the countries, etc

Comment: I didn't think about a survival model. You mean like a Cox proportional? Also I thought about controlling for distance, but there are lot of migrants that immigrate to places that are not border states, such as in W. Europe.

Comment: Yes exactly. But then I guess you would need a "time since applying for asylum"-metric. I see. Just trying to be creative :) Maybe there are more relevant things guiding the process, such as size of previous asylum groups from that country etc.

Comment: Some of the numbers really look random. For example, some individuals from country X will only go to country Y once in a twelve year period. Or not go in year T1 but then later in T3. Some of it is obvious, such as conflict. Others are maybe not fleeing conflict but for other reasons. This has given me a headache for some time now, so I decided to throw a life line out here on stackexchange.

Comment: If we take a step back, what is your research question?

Comment: Very simply, it looks at what are some domestic explanations that affect asylum-granting. So, for example, do far-Right parties in power in the host state really affect asylum-granting? If the host state has a different majority religion compared to those applying for asylum, does that affect asylum-granting? etc. The asylum-rates are the DV.

Comment: Ah, sorry misunderstood - thought it was disaggregate data at the individual level. I guess you will have to try and really use as much of the panel data setup as possible (e. g. lags of vars) with appropriate controls to convincingly disentangle the effects. Maybe utilize elections etc to identify such effects?

Comment: I should have been more clear, so thank you! I do include a lot of controls, and pooled as much as I could in order to lag. I wanted to use a GEE model, but I know it's not biased if it's MCAR only. That's what really got my head scratching.

Comment: I think this answer adds useful and thoughtful considerations, but there might be much more involved.  E.g., "missing due to pending decision" might reflect special circumstances that make such cases substantially different from the rest in the way the independent variables relate to the dependent.

Comment: Indeed. Just scratching my head as to what to do with pending numbers alongside the rate calculations.

Comment: A common strategy is to impute values for missing data and then compare regression (?) results under such imputation to results solely dependent on original data ("complete case analysis").  If they hardly differ, it adds justification for the latter analysis.

Comment: I read about imputation, but it also confused me since I'm dealing with asylum numbers. I'm not sure how to fill in the blanks without affecting the asylum rates. Say, I just put zeros for all the years that were missing, the asylum rates will be missing as well, since there were no recognition.